# detecting circles using hough transform

Tags: python, c++, opencv

i have the next code in python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('2.png',0)    
cv2.imshow('detected circles',img)    
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)    
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)    
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=30,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)    

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))    
for i in circles[0,:]:     
    # draw the outer circle     
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)     
    # draw the center of the circle     
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)     


cv2.imshow('detected circles1',cimg)
```

then when i tryed to use the same parameters in cpp the code doesnt detect all cyrceles in the image...

i tryed this code:

```
cv::medianBlur(mat, mat, 5);    
cv::Mat grayMat;     
cv::cvtColor(mat, grayMat, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);     
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles1;     
cv::HoughCircles(grayMat, circles1, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 30, 30, 0, 0);
```

the pic i am ising are:
[first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egXDO.jpg)
[second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azXjj.jpg)

what can be the problem?

Comment: None of this is MATLAB.

Comment: Can you show the sample images and results?

Comment: Is the color conversion right? Your Python code uses GRAY2BGR and c++ uses BGR2GRAY.

Comment: post images please

Comment: @boaz001 in cpp hough transform recivs grey scale pic (see http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)
and in python we need BGR (see http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html)

Comment: @AbdulFatir i added pic